# NodeJs Redis : Get 10 comments with each api call

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I am trying to retrieve 10 comments with each api call wrt to last datetime and post id as conditional parameter. Unable to retrieve desire result using HMGET or HGET :

Below is the code

```
redisClient.hget('comment', function(err, reply) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(reply));
        res.json(reply);
    });
```

In above code whr should i put conditional operation for 10 comments.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be better if you could show the code you are using and provide some details about the incorrect results you are seeing. Just saying "X doesn't work" is not enough information for anyone to help you.

Comment: @Lee, Sorry man i am new to StackOverflow. Please find below Code : 
redisClient.hget('comment', function(err, reply) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(reply));
        res.json(reply);
    });